# Using Styled Components, is there a way to select a className

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-dates

I am using StyledComponents in a React project, and I'm planning to overwriting the styles in Airbnb's react-dates library. They are using a CSS file with classes, but I want to overwrite their CSS using a wrapper component through StyledComponents (to keep my project consistent with not using CSS files).

Is this possible? I'm not finding anything on it.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Try to be as specific as possible to override other less specific CSS that may be blocking you.  Force it by adding `!important`.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure how to make a styled component more specific if you can't select classes or ids. With 4 or 5 different divs with different classes, how could you select these items? Basically I'm trying to create a wrapper component that's going to act very much like a standalone CSS file.

Comment: Like this:
`#TheID .theClassName .otherDIV .someDIV .divDIV .divitisDIV {color: purple!important;}`

Comment: Oh thanks, I probably should have tried that before asking the question. Not sure why I assumed that wouldn't work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: did it work okay?

Comment: Yep it worked as intended, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to be as specific as possible and if necessary add the `!important` flag.

For example:

`#TheID .theClassName .otherDIV .someDIV .divDIV .divitisDIV {
     color: purple!important;
}`